# JS, How can I remove text under conditions of starting at < and ending at >?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text html document and I would like to delete all html code and leave all the plain text.

```
<p>Random text generated by some method</p>
<p style="text-align:center;">centered text example</p>
<p>Full name</p>
<p>IRSP</p>
```

output should be:

```
Random text generated by some method centered text example Full name IRSP
```

I'm kinda of a new so any docs related to this are welcome.

Comment: Use an HTML parser

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the string and get the result's `textContent`:

```js
const str = `<p>Random text generated by some method</p>
<p style="text-align:center;">centered text example</p>
<p>Full name</p>
<p>IRSP</p>`

const res = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.textContent;
console.log(res)
```